# Document library field wont update field value

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

on ItemAdded on a field,

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            using (SPWeb web = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl).OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[properties.ListId];
                SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);
                var test = item["MyField"] = "";
                item.SystemUpdate(false);
            }

                this.EventFiringEnabled = true;

            }
        }

    }
```

when adding a dokument directly to my library its clear the field, men when i publish the document and then try to unpublish and then i select Remove this document but create a draft of the document, on this event it wont clear my field, i get the value and everything but in the en it still has the old value?

Answer (score 0):

I've not checked this for sure but I think I remember when dealing with event receivers in document libraries it's a little funny. I believe the itemAdded event fires when you upload the document, you then continue to fill out your metadata for that document and when you click save the itemupdating and itemupdated event is fired. If you debug you will see this I think.

I believe you want to change to ItemUpdated

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Thanks for your response, i cant use ItemUpdated because i update my field directly in the list, and when i update the field i have set it to clear when using itemupdated, i first set  the field in the list and then publish it after publishing it when unpublish the document i then want to clear the field, but when using itemupdated it will clear my field in both moments, i want to clear only in the second moment, that why i am using itemadded.

Comment: Switch it to itemUpdated ,when item updated check if the item is published or not and then action clearing the field when you want it to be done.

Comment: hmm, i have tried before with if(item.Level == SPFileLevel.Published) but then it says that the document is published even if i havent published it yet, because its already checkedin? in my document library where i first edit the field all always published and level 1

Comment: i want to have it like this, document is upload to library i have changed the field value save it, then i to publish, then it should do nothing, then when i unpublish it then it should update the value

Comment: are you sure your checking the level on the right object? switch to itemUpdated Check the level of the spListItem.File.Level != SPFileLevel.Published

Comment: File.Level gets published, so i will never update.. Publish could also check for if the document in checked in, i am talking about publishing workflow when user must accept to be published

Comment: The level are published everywere